# Not able to parse json in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, parsing

I'm using `jquery.parseJSON()` but it is not happening. What I'm doing is making an ajax call to server and then on success I try to parse data got from the server using `jquery.parseJSON()` but it is not working.

```
function getIdVals(id){
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: "MyServlet",
                data: "Id="+id,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    alert(html);
                    var obj = jquery.parseJSON(html);
                    alert(obj.data);
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

The response I got from server is something like below:

```
'{ "data" : "{ aas:five,asda:five,alskjaskdakbd:two,test:two,asddas:five,
             lasnd:five,ad:five,this:two,smd:five,alskjaskdakbdals:four,}"}'
```

When I try to put the above string in `jquery.parseJSON` function it works fine but don't know why writing it as `jquery.parseJSON(html)` doesn't work.

How can I solve this?

Comment: do you really have the values in json without quotes around? and what about strange comma in the end?

Comment: Comma at the end will be remove by some serve side loop change. Yes this is the exact string I got from server.

Comment: well, it doesn't look like valid json, that is why your code doesn't work

Comment: Why? If i put this string hardcoded in parseJson function it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the json you are getting is in valid it should be something like

```
{
    "data": {
        "aas": "five",
        "asda": "five",
        "alskjaskdakbd": "two",
        "test": "two",
        "asddas": "five",
        "lasnd": "five",
        "ad": "five",
        "this": "two",
        "smd": "five",
        "alskjaskdakbdals": "four"
    }
}
```

and then as @zerkms answered

```
function getIdVals(id){
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: "MyServlet",
                data: "Id="+id,
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json', // <<<<--------
                success: function(json){
                    // work with json here                    
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: I get it working. Thanks. Can you please tell me how can I loop through values once I got data object in json.

Comment: you can iterate the result using `$.each`

Answer (score 0):

You could specify `dataType: 'json'` attribute to the request, and you'll get parsed object in your function instead

```
function getIdVals(id){
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: "MyServlet",
                data: "Id="+id,
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json', // <<<<--------
                success: function(json){
                    // work with json here                    
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: use fire bug for debugging http://getfirebug.com/javascript, also check that you are getting the valid `json` you can check at www.jsonlint.com

Answer (score 0):

Your json is not correct. The bugs in json are:

```
'{ "data" : "{ aas:five,asda:five,alskjaskdakbd:two,test:two,asddas:five,
             lasnd:five,ad:five,this:two,smd:five,alskjaskdakbdals:four,}"}'
```

1. single quotes at start and at the end.
2. comma at the end of value.
3. It seems like you also want to get json data in value. So for that also wrap entries in value by quotes.

So a valid json will look like:

```
{ "data" : { "aas":"five","asda":"five","alskjaskdakbd":"two","test":"two",
            "asddas":"five","lasnd":"five","ad":"five","this":"two","smd":"five",
            "alskjaskdakbdals":"four"}}
```

Try to get this kind of json from server.

As far as jquery ajax call is concern I don't think any change is required if you are just getting this json string as the response on success function and if you are getting this as a part of response with some stuff then others have well explained it.

---

For your comment on **3nigma's** answer:

```
    $.each(obj.data, function(key,val) {
        alert(key+" "+val);
    });
```